# Trying to start a GUI process on a second machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, xorg

**Background**:

I am helping out create a media wall from spare computers/screens for a local university to use processing.org/java to distribute renders across several machines.
However, it's still buggy and I need to restart the clients occasionally.

**Problem**:

I'm currently having trouble figuring out how to re-launch the client java app remotely from the server. Note: the clients are connected directly to dual screens - rather than rendering headless

**Investigation**:

I have recreated a similar environment on AWS/EC2 where I can get the client-server model to work, but just can't start the gui client remotely. I keep getting:

> Can't open Display.

**Specific issue**:

Currently I use the following from the server:

> ssh ubuntu@guiclient1 "export DISPLAY=:0; cd ~/wallclient/; xclock &"

**Extra**:

I monitor the same guiclient1 desktop using x2go.
I haven't done any specific xauth / xhost configuration - as haven't seen any issues related to this yet.

What should I be configuring differently? I haven't found much help online - I don't want to do port forwarding back to server, which is what most questions answer.

Thanks

Comment: Right now I am unclear on what programs are running on which machines; what hardware is connected to each machine; and what shells are running (directly or by ssh) on which machines. So the advice below is necessarily general. If you want better advice you'll have to be *very* specific. Try listing the machines by name and purpose and telling us what shell you open on which machines.

Answer (score 0):

### For direct connection in X over the network

X has a permission model for allowing remote clients{*} to use a particular display. Read the manpage for `xhost`, but the short version is

```
server$ xhost remote_client
```

to interactively allow `remote_client` to use your screen.

Then on the client you just run

```
client$ xeyes
```

### Direct ssh

Connecting through a ssh is another matter. You should use the `-X` or `-Y` or set the corresponding values in .ssh/config (`ForwardX11` for -X). Your ssh client should then set the proper value for `DISPLAY` and you shouldn't mess with it.

```
server$ ssh -X client
client(by ssh)$ printenv DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
client(by ssh)$ xeyes
```

### Tunneling ssh

Open the tunnel through the firewall with something like

```
server$ ssh -X -L 1111:client:22 user@firewall
```

then in another shell

```
server$ ssh -X -p 1111 user@localhost
client(by ssh)$ printenv DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
client(by ssh tunnel)$ xeyes
```

(note the `-X` again) to open a shell running on `destination`. As with the direct ssh connection your `DISPLAY` variable should be set for you.

---

{*} Here I follow the X tradition of saying that the computer on which display occurs is the *server* because it makes its display available to multiple programs running on *client* mahcines.

This will probably seem backwards, as you are probably used to the machine your are working at being the "client" and the one tucked in the closet being the "server".

Comment: thanks @dmckee - this is useful and allows me to investigate further.
I did the following sequence:
client$ xhost +server

server$ ssh -X user@client
client (via ssh)$ printenv DISPLAY
which returns "", and nothing works off that

however the X2go client connects via localhost:53 or similar fine

Comment: maybe an issue with XAuthority? I notice there is no env variable set for it. Also double checking the ssh verbose connection - there is no mention of 'requesting x11 forwarding in the output'. 

One more learning exercise I think. :)

Comment: Is the issue that the 'server' is not running a graphical X client as well. 

server$ xhost +client also gives unable to open display "".

Comment: The machine on which the program is going to be displayed must be running a X server (note that `startx` and similar scripts start the "server" in the X notation---the program that makes the screen available to "client"s like `xclock`, `xeyes` and so on). The machine where the code runs need not be running a X server. Finally, ave you checked that you have X forwarding enabled in ssh?

Comment: ok, then my setup is ok from that aspect. x11 forwarding is enabled in both.